# jquery, fancybox, ie7 and a random white box i can't explain

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, fancybox

there's a random white box showing up in my ie7 below the footer. 
looks fine in firefox/safari 4/chrome.  i used debugger to inspect and it's showing up as a fancybox div.

thing is, i don't think i'm using fancybox anywhere.  confused.

http://bit.ly/bT2CI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View your source. It confirms you are using fancybox

You have the following js line (line 21 in the html)

```
$(".gallery a").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': true
    })
```

Comment: lol wow thanks
i knew it was something as easy as that.  been staring at my screen too long.